# Is ‘published-in’ a correct word in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> 1. To estimate the scientific value of academic articles, we should see
>    rankings of **journals that have published the articles**.
> 2. To estimate the scientific value of academic articles, we should see
>    rankings of **published-in journals**.

*Published-in journals* is meant to mean *journals that have published the articles*, that is, *the related/relevant journals* Is that a correct way of saying such thing. Can ‘published-in’ even be a word? Or maybe there is another choice I am not aware of?

Comment: Is this something you have seen somewhere? (if so then please give a link) Or is it something you're thinking of writing and want to see if it will be accepted?

Comment: @Mitch the latter.

Comment: OK cool. Using a hyphenated verb phrase like this is becoming more and more common in speech (so it is a natural thing to say), but it is not at all formal and should be avoided in writing (which is usually towards the more formal). Most teachers and editors would strike this down as plain wrong, but would be acceptable in very in formal speech.

Answer (score 3):

That is certainly not a standard way of expressing that idea; for one thing, you seem to mean that the "articles" are "published in" something, but "published-in" instead modifies "journals". Here is an example in which that construction (past participle-preposition) modifies the correct noun:

> That journalist has published many **talked-about** articles.

Probably the clearest way to express your idea with a past participle / passive voice would be:

> To estimate the scientific value of academic articles, we should see the rankings of journals in which they have been published.

However, this may not be better than your sentence #1, which uses the active voice.